# Can't Find Perfmon Results

Tags: windows-7, perfmon

On a Win7 box I've setup a User Defined collector set in perfmon.  I clicked on it to start it, waited 30 seconds, then clicked to stop.  My understanding was that I could go under the Reports folder and see an entry representing the stats the were collected for that 30 second period but I don't see anything.  When i go into the properties of the collector set I do see a tab for directory and configurations for how to name files.  When I went to that directory I didn't see any output files there as well.

I'm running with administrator privileges.

Is there some additional configuration needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs most likely because the user sets something wrong, therefore you have to re-cechk your settings. I prepared a small list here :

- User needs to have write access to the destination folder
- If you run it remotely, be sure to use a domain account
- re-check where you store the output file
  [image: check this field]
- check your stop condition (rightclick on data collector and properties. check if you selected a 0 second overall duration or some other mistake)
- if that doesn't help change the destination path to something else to re-check